# By or through for a rotation

Tags: terminology, rotations

"Rotated through pi rad" vs "Rotated by pi rad"

I have heard both used and also heard mentioned that there was a mathematical difference between the two. Is this true or can they be used interchangeably?

Should I be asking whether there is a grammatical difference in the English forum?

Comment: The thing about mathematical terminology is that clarity is the first and foremost goal. The most common reasons why a particular piece of terminology in mathematics is bad is either that it has common use elsewhere, or because it's a new name for something that already has a common name. I've heard both as well, and I've never heard of either terminology being used for anything else. I'm going out on a limb and saying both are perfectly fine.